# Difference between shareable and non-shareable libraries for linking

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, configure

At the moment I'm installing [MPICH](http://www.mpich.org/) on a cluster. For `configure`, there is a parameter `--enable-shared`, "to have shared libraries created when MPICH is built" ([installation manual](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.0.4/mpich-3.0.4-installguide.pdf), page 9). This acts only as example, my question is MPICH agnostic: is there a difference between "shareable" and "non-shareable" libraries?

Until now I assumed there are only different ways of integrating a library (static, dynamic, late linking), but

- are there also different library types?
- If yes, what are the differences, especially technical differences? Are non-shareable libraries compiled differently or contain less functionality?
- If no, what is it about the MPICH installation manual entry?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> is there a difference between "shareable" and "non-shareable" libraries

Yes: shared libraries can be shared between different executables using them.

Archive libraries (are the opposite of shared) and can only be shared when you use multiple instances of the same executable, but not between different executables.

EDIT:

> Is there a drawback of using shareable libraries

There are several:

- Calling into shared library, as well as calls and global data accesses within the library are a tiny bit slower (usually 1-2%, but could be 10% in extreme cases). There are [mitigation techniques](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), but they are not trivial.
- Use of shared libraries requires that you ship to the target system *both* the main executable, *and* all the shared libraries it requires (and correct versions of these shared libraries). This may become a significant problem once the number of libraries approaches 100.
- Use of shared libraries opens the door for "[DLL hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell)" and various weird errors when the shared library versions on your development system doesn't match versions on your production/cluster/customer system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a drawback of using shareable libraries? Otherwise, what is the justification for non-shareable libraries at all?